# Change styles.sass to styles.scss in Angluar

Tags: angular, sass

We have a bit of a mess on an Angular project where the main styles is set up as a sass file and the rest of the page stylesheets are .scss files.

I want to change the sass file to scss, but when I rename it, the site build breaks.

What else do I need to do to?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ng config`, you can change the default style extension to `scss`.

```
ng config defaults.styleExt=scss
```

After configuring this, change the sass file and it will work.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm getting a "Value cannot be found." error when I run the command in Terminal.  I'm in the Root of the Angular project.

Comment: Then try this config. `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss`

Comment: Thanks Derek.W.  That ran, but I'm still getting an error when I compile as below.  I'm guessing this is the material design icons dependency?

```ERROR in multi ./node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css ./src/custom-theme.scss ./src/styles.sass```

```Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '[Angular Root Folder]/src/styles.sass' in '[Angular Root Folder]'```

Comment: Where have you added the styles? It is needed to update the `angular.json` file regarding the style part.

Comment: From `style.sass` to `style.scss` and update the referenced parts.